# Need access query to reflect the data with latest date/follow up field

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am creating the a database and almost complete. I have issue in creating the query to show the data with latest date from incident report number without repeating. If the date is same for the incident report number then need the data with latest follow up from incident report number without repeating.

I have attached the report showing the first data's as actual [Actual Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUZEP.png) and second data as required [Required Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Qaf.png). Highlighted are the field which are need to concentrate on.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a filter: `[Follow Up] = ".1"`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I am looking for answer to my requested question. Its not the answer.

Comment: Then your sample data are not representative.